# how to find a row value which contains every possible values of another column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame with IDs, months and statuses. There are several rows for each ID, each representing a month and the status in the given month. I want to find the IDs which have all the possible statuses. How do I do this?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[11, 11, 12, 12],
                     'Month':[1, 2, 1, 2],
                     'Status':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']})
print(df)
   ID  Month Status
0  11      1      a
1  11      2      a
2  12      1      a
3  12      2      b
```

I wish to find the code that outputs 12, since that is the ID that contains all possible status values ('a' and 'b' in this case)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because theOP wants us to write code without any code hint from his side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a [`crosstab`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) and then only considering rows with all non-zero elements:

```
#Creates a crosstab the variable 'Status'
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Status'])
#Considers only rows where all values are non-zero
df1 = df1[(df1.T != 0).all()]
```

```
print(df1)

Status  a  b
ID          
12      1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> df2 = df.groupby('ID').aggregate(set)
>>> df2

     Month  Status
ID      
11  {1, 2}  {a}
12  {1, 2}  {b, a}

>>> max_states = 2   # you should know that
>>> list(df2[df2.apply(lambda x: len(x['Status'])==max_states, axis=1)].index)

[12]
```